# Sending an array of objects via AJAX - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So getting the objects I need in JS, I did:

```
$('.combine-payment-input').each(function (index, value) {
    if (parseFloat(value.value) > 0) {
       if (methodOfPayment == -1) {
            methodOfPayment = value.dataset.method;
       }
       else {
           methodOfPayment = 0;
       }
       vmopl.push({
            id: value.dataset.method,
            name: $('label[for="' + value.id + '"]').html(),
            inUse: 'True',
            ammount: value.value
       });
    }
});
```

If I `console.log` `vmopl` in the end, I'll get something like

```
[Object { id="2",  name="Card",  inUse="True",  ammount="500"}, 
    Object { id="1",  name="Cash",  inUse="True",  ammount="250"}]
```

Now if I try to send this to AJAX this up using

```
$.get('/reports/savebill/' + methodOfPayment + '?vmop=' + JSON.stringify(vmopl), function (data) {
    if (data == 'True') {
        location.href = '/order/neworder/';
    } else {
        alert("Unsuccessful!");
    }
});
```

A controller action *Should* pick `vmop` up, the controller looks like so:

```
public bool SaveBill(int id, ViewMethodOfPayment[] vmop) { 
    //lots of code... 
}
```

But when I put a breakpoint, I always see `vmop` as null, even when I pass it to another object (`var temp = vmop;`).

`ViewMethodOfPayment` is a simple model class:

```
public class ViewMethodOfPayment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool InUse { get; set; }
    public double Ammount { get; set; }
}
```

If I missed any info, or if it's unclear what I want to do/expect, please leave a comment, I'll answer as soon as I can!

Thanks for reading!

edit: changed the first block of code (line: 9, because I included a code that will bring a JavaScript error)

Comment: It would be very easy if you just serialize the form!

Comment: what about if you send data in **POST** method :)

Comment: instead of `ViewMethodOfPayment[] vmop` try putting `List<ViewMethodOfPayment> vmop`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I'm going to try that.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I'll try that first, actually, I'll respond with the result

Comment: and also use **List** or **IEnumerable** to get in Action Method

Comment: Tried putting it in a **List**, but brings back empty List (Count = 0). I'll try what @VuongNQ said real quick

Comment: I see you have some spelling mistake in `JSON.stringift(vmopl)`!! Have you made a note? Shouldn't it be `JSON.stringify(vmopl)`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Fixed, it's an error I made here, not in the code. Possibly while editing the question.

Comment: I feel your model is not getting the values properly because the properties inside it are case sensitive. So either while pushing to vmop assign it as it is in `model` like `id` should be `Id`.. Try once..

Comment: Just tried, nadda @GuruprasadRao. I'll try what MilConDoin suggested, if it doesn't work, I'll try to take a difference approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I currently use:

Javascript sends the data via JSON.stringify, like you do.

C#:

```
public ActionResult AjaxDoSomething(string vmop)
{
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        var parameter = jss.Deserialize<ViewMethodOfPayment []>(vmop);
        //Do something with this data and return the desired result
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have thought of that, but purely because of that extra step (performance wise, this web service won't go on a super fast server), I'm keeping it as a last resort.

Edit: I'm reading the edit now, I'll try that next, might take me a few.

Comment: Good point, the OP typically sends out a string, not an array since he uses `JSON.stringify(vmopl)`.

Comment: I'm not sure how clear it could be from a comment like this, but it pretty much works! (thank you very much!). @TasosK. gave me a clarification that it's a string already, so I took it as such (such as before you edited the parameter in the answer) and turned it into an objects as you wrote it. Thanks you again!

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the wrong parameter type in my edited example. That was a blunder on my part and is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

try putting [FromUri] before ViewMethodOfPayment[] vmop as below

```
public bool SaveBill(int id,[FromUri] ViewMethodOfPayment[] vmop) { 
//lots of code... 
}
```

Comment: Will try that in a bit.

Comment: [FromUri] doesn't belong to any known annotation library? where do you implement it from?

Comment: if your controller inherits from ApiController you can use [FromUri]

Comment: Problem is, since this is a team project, making it extend ApiController is out of the question